# How to run html & javascript in VS Code

Tags: javascript, html, vscode-debugger

I have the following code. How do I run this in VS Code with the debugger. I installed and tried live-server but maybe not doing it correctly.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Test</button>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var fn = () => console.log(this)

function fn() {
  console.log(this);
}

button.addEventListener('click', fn)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install the following extensions.

1. Live Server.
2. Chrome Debugger.

Once you have these two extensions installed, open the page `index.html` using the live server and then press `F12` to open the developer tools for chrome.

And then you can paste a single line of code on the debugger like this.

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',()=>{
     console.log("Event Raised");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Test</button>
  <script>
    const button = documnet.querySelector("button")
    if(button) {
       button.addEventListener("click", () => {
          console.log("This Works")
       })
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run **live server** but I suggest you to use [lite-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server) library.

---

1. Run this command in terminal inside project folder to initialize project with `npm init -y`
2. Add lite-server to your devDependencies with `npm install lite-server --save-dev`
3. Add `start` command to run server to **package.json**

   "scripts": {
   "start": "lite-server"
   },

> To start server use `npm start`